# Swapping 2 Nodes in a Linked List

Tags: c

Good day guys, im new here to C and am trying to learn linked lists. I been trying to swap 2 nodes from within a linked list but so far have been having trouble getting it to work. The code I been trying to use causes an endless circular loop, but I don't think it is because of the if or while statement.

Take a look? Any pointers here? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Basically, the code uses a user input to search for a node based on the data inside, then it should swap the node with the data inside with the next node. Been at this for 3 hours, can anybody help? Thanks!

/*conductor is the name im using of the pointer for the current node*/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int x;
  struct node *next;
  struct node *prev;
};

struct node *root;
struct node *conductor;
struct node *counter;
struct node *newnode;
struct node *back;

struct node *swapper;
struct node *swappee;
struct node *blanker;

int add = 0;
int initialization = 0;
int query = 0;

int swap ()
{

printf("enter data to search from within the nodes: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d", &query);

conductor = root;
while ( conductor->next != 0)
    {
        if(conductor->x == query)
        {
        printf("\n%d\n", query);
        swapper = conductor;
        swappee = conductor->prev;
        conductor = swappee;
        conductor->next = swapper;
        break;
        }
        else
        {
        conductor = conductor->next;
        }
    }

mainMenu ();
```

}

Comment: Please format your code better, thanks.

Comment: inside the body of your `else` block, try printing `conductor->x`, and if you still haven't found the problem, than post the output from that.  That will help you (and us) understand what's going on

Comment: swap the x member of node.

Comment: That's a lot of global variables. Why not move them into the functions that use them?

Comment: "Any pointers here?"   - Hah, I get it!

Comment: Hahahahaha, very funny

Answer (score 1):

A double linked list (like the one you have) is basically an array of node, each node pointing to its neighbors. Let's say we have nodes -A-B-C-D- (A-B means that A points to B and B points to A). Let's say you want to swap B and C. You have to make 4 changes:

- Make A point to C
- Make C point to B and A
- Make B point to D and B
- make D point to B

You make only the second and the third change. So, you need to add `A->next = B` and `D->prev=C`. I hope it is clear enough.

Also, you should not fflush input streams.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap the data:

```
if (conductor->x == query) {
    int temp = conductor->x;
    if (conductor->next)
        conductor->x = conductor->next->x;
        conductor->next->x = temp;
    }
}
```

Typically that is what you will want to do. If you have a structure with several members instead of the 1 `int`, swapping the pointers may seem less messy in theory, but it isn't, primarily due to the fact that you must test for existence of a next/previous node so often. In truth, you'd probably want a pointer to a separate structure in such a case.

Given three nodes — `previous`, `current`, and `next`, pointing to `current->prev`, `current`, and `current->next` respectively — you must update at most 6 pointers:

1. next->prev = previous
2. previous->next = next
3. current->prev = next
4. current->next = next->next
5. next->next = current
6. current->next->prev = current

Step 2 is not necessary if `previous` is `NULL`.
Step 7 is unnecessary if `current->next` is `NULL`.

The entire thing is unnecessary if `next` is `NULL`.

If you want to swap with the previous node instead of the next, exchange any instance of the variable `previous` with the variable `next` and vice-versa as well as exchanging any instance of `->prev` with `->next` and vice-versa.

Overall, this requires a fair bit of branching code, which can be slow. This is why it is usually better to swap the data rather than messing with the pointers. It gets even messier when you want to swap with the previous node and you only have a singly-linked list that points to the next node because you must store yet another pointer for the equivalent of `previous->prev`, assuming `previous` exists.